# How to return null values for editing in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce, checkout

I know this might be a silly question for the MVC pros but it become a headache for me for the last couple of hours so please accept my excuses!
I have a class called `DeliveryDetails` as below:

```
Public Class DeliveryDetails 
{
   Prop1;
   Prop2;
   Prop3;
   PropX;
}
```

The concept is that i want the logged in users to **edit** the `DeliveryDetails` class data as a process of checkout even if there is no data in the backend database table. Is that possible? Or should i first save the DeilveryDetails and on the second time of purchasing i bring up DeliveryDetails in editing mode?

Comment: what type is of prop1, prop2, prop3? are they list or strings?

Comment: No they are strings and int. what difference would it make it was a list? @Bharat

Comment: Just create a new instance of `DeliveryDetails` and pass it to the view.

Comment: if there is data allow them to edit , else you allow them to add delivery details

Comment: @StephenMuecke Need your help as all the time, a quick example would be much enough! Thank you

Comment: You have not given enough information to give your an example.

Comment: Question will be updated soon will tag you on a comment after editing. @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head, based on your input:

You could create DeliveryDetails and store its reference into Session on Session_Start event (you could also load it from database or some other source, if neccessary).

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["DeliveryDetails"] = new DeliveryDetails();
}
```

Then when you need your DeliveryDetails instance, you just extract it from session like this:

```
var deliveryDetails = (DeliveryDetails)Session["DeliveryDetails"];
// deliveryDetails.Prop1 = ...
// deliveryDetails.Prop2 = ...
// etc.
```

But in this way, you must be careful to init/reset DeliveryDetails object inside Session, when it is appropriate.

This way you can decide when to write data into database (if required), but the user will have its DeliveryDetails always available through Session. Of course, if you do not use Sessions, you may not be able to do this.